# How to stop power shell script on error?

Tags: bash, powershell, docker, jenkins, asp.net-core

I have bellow script

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop";

while($true) {
try {
Write-Host "Step 1"; 
Dir C:\arts #Error
Write-Host "Step 2";
exit 0
break;
}
catch {
"Error in " + $_.InvocationInfo.ScriptName + " at line: " + $_.InvocationInfo.ScriptLineNumber + ", offset: " + $_.InvocationInfo.OffsetInLine + ".";
$Error
exit 1
break;
}
}
```

It stops on `Dir C:\arts` line and that is good for me. As I understood it happens cos I have line `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop";` at the beginning.

I also have some docker [params](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/blob/master/samples/core/docker/building-net-docker-images/dockerTask.ps1)

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ParameterSetName="Compose")]
    [switch]$Compose,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ParameterSetName="ComposeForDebug")]
    [switch]$ComposeForDebug,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ParameterSetName="StartDebugging")]
    [switch]$StartDebugging,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ParameterSetName="Build")]
    [switch]$Build,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ParameterSetName="Clean")]
    [switch]$Clean,
    [parameter(ParameterSetName="Compose")]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="ComposeForDebug")]
    [parameter(ParameterSetName="Build")]
    [parameter(ParameterSetName="Clean")]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [String]$Environment = "Debug"
)
```

If I put `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"` line before docker params I will have error `Cannot convert value "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter". Boolean parameters accept only Boolean values and numbers, such as $True, $False, 1 or 0.`

In case if I put `$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop";` line after docker params, script is continued to run and that is not that I want.

I do not know what I need to do here, so I will be grateful for any help

Comment: The params are not just for docker. They are for the script. Have you tried putting your line within the parenthesis? e.g. below `[String]$Environment = "Debug"`

Comment: yep, I was trying to do it, but I do not know what syntax is to use here

I was trying to do `[String]$ErrorActionPreference= "Stop"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$ErrorActionPreference` doesn't work with command line utilities like docker as they don't throw exceptions in PowerShell. You would have to use returncode/errorlevel or parse the output to handle those type of errors. Useful automatic variables:

> **$?**
>      Contains the execution status of the last operation. It contains
>      TRUE if the last operation succeeded and FALSE if it failed.
>
> **$LastExitCode**
>
> Contains the exit code of the last Windows-based program that was run. Same as %errorlevel% in cmd.

If you detect an error, you can throw an exception to stop the script or use something like `exit` to stop the script. Example:

```
function Test-Error {
    $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

    Write-Host Before
    ping -n 1 123.123.123.123

    #If last command was not successfull.
    #You can also have checked $lastexitcode, output etc.
    if($? -eq $false) {
        #Throw terminating error
        #throw "Error"

        #Or since we've chosen to stop on non-terminating errors, we could use:
        Write-Error -ErrorId $LASTEXITCODE -Message "Ping failed"
    }
    Write-Host After
}

Test-Error
```

Output:

```
Before

Pinging 123.123.123.123 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 123.123.123.123:
    Packets: Sent = 1, Received = 0, Lost = 1 (100% loss),
Test-Error : Ping failed
At line:22 char:1
+ Test-Error
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 1,Test-Error
```

If you're creating a advanced function, you could set the default ErrorAction for the scope of the cmdlet like this:

```
function Test-Error {
    [CmdLetBinding()]
    param(
        $Name = "World"
    )

    #If -ErrorAction is not specified by the user, use Stop for the scope of the function
    if(-not $MyInvocation.BoundParameters.ContainsKey("ErrorAction")) { $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop" }

    "Hello $Name ! My ErrorAction is: $ErrorActionPreference"
}

PS > $ErrorActionPreference
Continue

PS > Test-Error -ErrorAction Ignore
Hello World ! My ErrorAction is: Ignore

PS > Test-Error
Hello World ! My ErrorAction is: Stop
```